# Fitting data to a probability distribution, maybe skew normal?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am trying to fit my data to some kind of a probability distribution, so I can then generate random numbers based on the distribution. Below is what the data points look like, with x-axis behind the data values and y-axis the probabilities.

[Data plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH8vK.png)

They look like they would fit to a skew normal distribution, with mean around 10^-4. The plot's data is actually binned from an original data set. I tried using `scipy.stats` library to fit to a skew normal on the original data, but the fit does not work at all.

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to fit this to any PDF? The data in my plot is below (can't post the original, raw data as it is far too large):

```
x = [2.0030289496413441e-07, 6.021220996561269e-07, 1.8100138940039783e-06, 5.4410065638820868e-06, 1.6355980761406714e-05, 4.916702516834233e-05, 0.00014779892439152631, 0.00044429212417263257, 0.0013355678494582283, 0.0040147942838919017, 0.012068704071088232, 0.036279223206999923, 0.10905744550124194, 0.32783299552460016, 0.98548496584223111, 2.9624248661943691, 8.9052206700550585, 26.769608940074498, 80.470994415019419, 241.90046842440222, 727.16681394735679, 2185.9055451626773, 6570.9586311220974, 19752.682098944373]

y (or P(x) in the diagram) = [2.2554525565554728e-05, 2.2554525565554728e-05, 3.1576335791776624e-05, 0.0013140978842667934, 0.00029833486088983759, 0.00083417571068968434, 0.0013023224717182351, 0.00030292744905932074, 0.00018784462533064236, 0.00015960011900197359, 5.231239486282394e-05, 4.8227744123750205e-05, 3.8972462681781172e-05, 2.9372389964277703e-05, 3.3001942979800356e-05, 2.8061790992628833e-05, 2.6056781088158009e-05, 2.522638138246609e-05, 2.4144908778509908e-05, 2.5086756895368843e-05, 2.3095834179128078e-05, 2.2554525565554745e-05, 2.2554525565554755e-05, 2.2554525565554728e-05]
```

Comment: *"I tried using scipy.stats library to fit to a skew normal on the original data, but the fit does not work at all."*  If you showed what you tried and what didn't work the way you expected, someone might be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.stats.skewnorm.fit` (see the docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html)) to fit the data into a skew-normal distribution.

`skewnorm.fit` returns maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) for shape, location, and scale parameters from data.

```
from scipy import stats

# define your dataset here

# let's make a sample with pre-defined parameters to demonstrate how it works
a, loc, scale = 1.6, -0.2, 3.2
data = stats.skewnorm(a, loc, scale).rvs(10000)

# estimate parameters of the sample
a_estimate, loc_estimate, scale_estimate = stats.skewnorm.fit(data)
print(a_estimate, loc_estimate, scale_estimate)
```

Output:

> 1.5784198343540448 -0.18066366859003175 3.1817350641737274