# Not sure what distribution to use to model my data

Tags: numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of astronomical data, to which I'm trying to fit a curve:

[image]

My fitting code is

```
param = stats.norm.fit(df['delta z'].dropna())   # Fit a normal distribution to the data
pdf_fitted = stats.norm.pdf(df['delta z'], *param)
x = np.linspace(*df['delta z'].agg([min, max]), 1000) # x-values
binwidth = np.diff(edges).mean()
ax.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, *param)*h.sum()*binwidth, color = 'r')
```

which produces

[image]

Now, I'm clearly doing this in the wrong way, because the curve doesn't fit the data at all. All of the tutorials I've seen, such as [here](http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_curve_fit.html) involve making a set of data, in which case we already know things like the mean and the skew. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358964/fitting-data-to-a-probability-distribution-maybe-skew-normal?rq=1) led me to estimate the parameters with

```
a_estimate, loc_estimate, scale_estimate = stats.skewnorm.fit(df['delta z'])
ax.plot(x, skewnorm.pdf(x, a_estimate, loc_estimate, scale_estimate), 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='skewnorm pdf')
```

which produces

[image]

so how can I plot the fit with those parameters?

Comment: I have an online statistical distribution fitter at http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/ that will try fitting your data to the over 85 statistical distributions in scipy, just paste in your data and hit the Submit button. It might suggest a few candidate distributions.

Comment: Why are you fitting a distribution to the data?  What will you do with the distribution? Could you do what you want with just the [empirical CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function), or perhaps with [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)?

Comment: I just need to plot the distribution and show the mean and standard deviation on the plot.

Comment: You can get the mean and standard deviation *from the data*.  I still don't see why you need to fit a distribution to it.   Do you have some model of the process that generated the data that could guide your choice of a distribution?  If you really just want a smooth curve to plot over your histogram, then kernel density estimation should work reasonably well.  See, for example, [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).

Comment: I've used `a_estimate, loc_estimate, scale_estimate = stats.skewnorm.fit(x)` to find the parameters, I just don't know how to plot the curve.

Comment: It looks like what you did should have worked.  It is possible that the optimization routine used by the `fit` method didn't work (although one would hope that it would raise an error, or at least a warning, in that case).  Can you post the data somewhere?

Comment: I've put the data into a csv file. The columns I've plotted are `z` 
 and `delta z`. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BJPIJWhQi6f2u76SlJa8T3-eThwnMGO8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you state that you don't know how to plot the curve: here is a small example fitting and plotting skewnorm.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = ss. expon.rvs(size=1000)

P = ss.expon.fit(data)
rX = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 50)
rP = ss.skewnorm.pdf(rX, *P)

plt.hist(data,bins=25, normed=True, color='slategrey')

plt.plot(rX, rP, color='darkturquoise')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to produce a smooth curve, rather than a histogram for the `plt.plot` of `rX` and `rP`? Also, how do I find the mean and variance for display in the legend?

Comment: EDIT to comment: Got the curve; how do I find the mean and variance for display in the legend? If I use `mean, var, skew, kurt = skewnorm.stats(a_est, moments='mvsk')`, the number it gives me for the mean doesn't match the curve.

Comment: I would first try numpy.mean(data) and numpy.var(data).

Comment: `np.mean` gives `-3e-15`, but the mean of the data is clearly closer to `1`.

Comment: What do you get for numpy.sum(data)? a few large negative values plus many smaller positive values could give both numpy.mean() and numpy.sum() of nearly zero.

Comment: `np.sum` gives a similarly very small number (10^-13). Sure it can, but the issue is that the curve peaks at about 1, but the `np.mean=-3e-15` and `mean, var, skew, kurt = skewnorm.stats(a_est, moments='mvsk')` gives a mean of `-0.74988` and `skewnorm.fit(x)` gives a `loc` of `2.578`. What parameter in `skewnorm` tells me the position of the curve peak, and the spread of it?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html has the information on this distribution and the scipy related functions for it. If numpy is not broken, the mean of your data is effectively zero.

Comment: Ok, from the docs, if I use `a_est, loc_est, scale_est = skewnorm.fit(x)` then `skewnorm.mean(a_est, loc_est, scale_est) = -0.0563`, but the peak of the curve sits at about 1. Maybe I should post another question?

Comment: If the distribution is highly skewed, then the peak of the curve won't be at the mean value, will it? Maybe that's the problem.