# Skewnorm not fitting properly

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

This is a follow-up to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961468/not-sure-what-distribution-to-use-to-model-my-data). I'm trying to fit my data from [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BJPIJWhQi6f2u76SlJa8T3-eThwnMGO8) csv file with `scipy.stats.skewnorm`, but I can't get it working right:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import skewnorm

df = pd.read_csv('astro_data.csv')
x = df['delta z']
number_bins = 50

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h, edges, _ = ax.hist(x, alpha = 0.5,
                      density = False,
                      bins = number_bins)

a_est, loc_est, scale_est = skewnorm.fit(x)
ax.plot(x, skewnorm.pdf(x, a_est, loc_est, scale_est), 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='skewnorm pdf')
```

[image]

Can anyone see how I can fix this?

EDIT: when I change to `density=True`, the result is this:

[image]

Comment: *"Can anyone see how I can fix this?"* Change the `density` argument of `hist` to `density=True`, so the histogram and the PDF use the same vertical scale.

Comment: But that also changes the absolute numbers to a relative fraction, which I don't want. Also, I'll put the resulting graph in the question. I don't understand why I'm not getting a smooth curve.

Comment: The mess of lines in the second plot happens because the `x` values that you are plotting are not sorted. You could sort `x`, or, instead of using `x`, use `xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 400); ax.plot(xx, skewnorm.pdf(xx, ...`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser what does the `400` refer to?

Comment: Check out the [`linspace` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

Comment: Ah, so it defines the 'resolution' of the fit.